# How to setup bastion host or Jumpbox in AWS?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am exploring how to setup bastion host like security and networking configuration on AWS.

lets say I have multiple EC2 instances. But I do not want to enable SSH on every other EC2 instance. I want to use a specially configured EC2 instance as a bastion host on which I can do SSH from my private IP (only); and once I am on bastion host instance or Jumpbox instance, I want to do SSH to any other EC2 instance in my VPC.

Is there any AMI instance available which I can use as a Jumpbox or bastion host? So that I can use only one bastion host to do SSH into any other EC2 instances within my VPC.

I saw few jumpbox EC2 AMI, but I guess they are being used more like Bitnami type of distribution and not acting as bastion host.

Comment: Is there no scenario where you will ever need a bastion host on AWS ? Because it appears that SG will resolve the issue for at least ssh connection.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As AWS Security Groups will allow you to Allow a particular IP, or particular range of IPs for SSH Inbound, it's kind of pointless having a Bastion Host for this use case. The [Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html) teach you how to do this.

The only time you would need a Bastion Host on AWS is if you need to SSH into instances that are in a private subnet. To get at instances in a private subnet from the Internet, you need to SSH into an instance in a public subnet, and from that bastion instance you would need to SSH to your instance in the private subnet using it's private IP.

It's pretty simple to set up. You don't need any fancy AMIs or anything like that and it only really needs to be something small like a t2.micro. Just Launch any instance eg.Amazon Linux in a public subnet. Make sure it's security group allows your IP on port 22, and SSH into it. Then you'll need to allow the bastion host access to your desired instances with security groups.

Once you have this set up, you can SSH into your bastion, and from there you can simply SSH into your desired instance.

These links might help you:

[Securely connect to Linux Instance in Private Subnet in VPC](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3N8GFK85UN1G6/Securely-connect-to-Linux-instances-running-in-a-private-Amazon-VPC)

[Controlling Network Access to EC2 instance using Bastion Server](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2ZWDW1QA6D62Y/Controlling-network-access-to-EC2-instances-using-a-bastion-server)

However, another way around accessing instances in a Private Subnet is to set up a VPN.

But the best way to lock down your instances is to use security groups and only allow your desired IPs to your instances.

Answer (score 15):

As of [Sep 21, 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/linux-bastion-hosts-on-the-aws-cloud-quickstart-reference-deployment/), AWS has published a [Quick Start](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/) reference deployment (a CloudFormation template and associated assets) that sets up a bastion host for securely accessing instances in a private VPC:

- [Linux Bastion Hosts on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/linux-bastion/) - welcome page
- [Linux Bastion Hosts on the AWS Cloud: Quick Start Reference Deployment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/welcome.html) - Deployment Guide
- [aws-quickstart/quickstart-linux-bastion](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-linux-bastion) - source code on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AWS CDK, you can put it in a separate stack, and pass your network config and security group as parameters. I prepared the solution in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/konarskis/7217d16f943d0c2405629fdef268f806) and went a little bit more in detail in [this post](https://open.substack.com/pub/konarskis/p/deploy-and-secure-a-bastion-host?r=1m5zop&utm_campaign=post&utm_medium=web&showWelcomeOnShare=true).

Most importantly:

- Keep a relatively up-to-date AMI
- Do not allow access from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0) in the security group
- Do not store any credentials other than public SSH keys on the bastion host

Answer (score -3):

If a web-based solution is adequate, you should try Bastillion

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B076D7XMK6

You can even use tags to restrict user access to instances.

http://www.bastillion.io/docs/bastillion-ec2/profiles