# Need help to winscp to the private linux instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, winscp

I have an instance in AWS with private IP (no public dns and no public ip) and I would like to connect to this instance through winscp to download few logs to my local PC. When I try to connect to this private instance through winscp I get below error, obviously because the server is in private.

[image]

Usually I ssh to bastion server which is in public subnet and then from there with private ssh key I ssh to the private instance. I could able to winscp to this bastion server which is in public but I would require to winscp to the private instance. I tried winscp connection tunnel hoping it might help somehow but I got "authentication key" error. Is there any way to winscp to private instance in AWS.

Comment: I am bit new here and would like to know the reason for 1 downvote. I dont see any reason why this question should be downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tutorial http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html to setup an SSH tunnel to be followed on the publicly accessible machine to link to the private one.

More opinions here [How to setup bastion host or Jumpbox in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667095/how-to-setup-bastion-host-or-jumpbox-in-aws).